# Relative positioning of nodes in TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Is it possible to align a corner of a finite-sided node like rectangle with the center of another node.

I am using a circle and a rectangle as an example in following code. Red filled rectangle in following figure is the desired location that I did manually. Using "right=of " option is giving me a shifted node

OUTPUT:
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance = 0mm]

% Gridline
\draw [step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
\node (ref1) [circle,red,fill=red,minimum size=1mm] at (-3.5,3.5) {};

% BackGround Box
\node (BG1) at (-4,3.5) [draw=red, fill=red!10, thick,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=7cm, xshift=2cm, yshift=-3.5cm] {};

% Position using relative locationing
\node (BG1) [draw=black, fill=none, thick,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=7cm, right=of ref1.east,anchor=north west] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am looking for a generalized solution that allows aligning two nodes relative to their centers, corners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual (page 51), using `at (coordinate)` is a general approach that will "always work."  It does not require the positioning library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance = 0mm]

% Gridline
\draw [step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
\node (ref1) [circle,red,fill=red,minimum size=1mm] at (-3.5,3.5) {};

% BackGround Box
\node (BG1) at (-4,3.5) [draw=red, fill=red!10, thick,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=7cm, xshift=2cm, yshift=-3.5cm] {};

% Position using relative locationing
\node (BG1) [draw=black, fill=none, thick,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=7cm,anchor=north west] at (ref1.east) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```